# Show tooltip on map marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I want to show twitter bootstrap `tooltip` option when I hover on map marker so I do this:

```
function createMarker(place){
    var placeLoc=place.geometry.location;

      var image = 'https://mts.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-a.png&psize=14&font=fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf&color=fffa4c38&ax=44&ay=48&scale=1';


    marker = new RichMarker({
          position: placeLoc,
          shadow: 0,
          map: map,
      content: '<div class="kikonica" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"><img src='+image+'</img></div>',
          });
```

So my marker is html code with class .kikonica . I try to add tooltip with:

```
$(function() {
  $('.kikonica').tooltop({placement: 'right'});
});
```

bt dont work. What is problem here?
I really dont understand why I cant show tooltip on map-marker hover...
please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance it Looks like you have a typo.

$('.kikonica').**tooltop**({placement: 'right'});

```
$(function() {
  $('.kikonica').tooltip({placement: 'right'});
});
```

**Edit: 1**

I think you have to have a title attribute for the tooltip to work.

...

```
content: '<div title="my tooltip text" class="kikonica" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"><img src='+image+'</img></div>',
```

...

**Edit 2**

// check if .kikonica exists

```
$(function() {

  alert ($('.kikonica').length);

if($('.kikonica').length > 0){

  $('.kikonica').tooltip({placement: 'right'});
}
});
```

**Edit 3**

```
setTimeout(function(){

$('.kikonica').tooltip({placement: 'right'});

},50); // increse this value (50) to higher if needed
```

**Edit 4**
Use this signature

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {

     $('.kikonica').tooltip({placement: 'right'});

  });
```

Comment: no, again is the same, as you can see on my demo page image: http://i.imgur.com/8gWPNxh.png

Comment: I also try with:  google.maps.event.addListener('.kikonica', 'mouseover', function() {
        $('.kikonica').tooltip();
    });

Comment: @drCode Whitout more information or a fidle with an example it's hard to sat what is happening. Please try to check if element .kikonica exists on domready. See my edit

Comment: this return me a 0, so my marker is dinamicly addeded after I click on button... maybe this is problem?

Comment: I also try:  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function(evt) {
        $('.kikonica').tooltip('show');
    });

Comment: @drCode Your problem is almost certainly due to the element '. Kikonica' does not exist in the Dom at the time of creating the marker. Thats why it returns zero. Try settimeout function. See my edit

Comment: ok, this is cool, but I dont know why dont work with google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function(evt) { $('.kikonica').tooltip('show'); }); ... so when google load all elements to start a function, becouse not every time script need 50 or 500 ms ...

Comment: @drCode I bet with the setTimeout function less than 50 works well. )
neveless i think you're not creating the event maps in a more effective way. See edit

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party... But I would add the tooltip when the map is fully loaded to ensure correct tooltip behavior. Adding it on mouseover prevents it from displaying the very first hover.

```
    // Add tooltips when map is fully loaded
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
        $('.kikonica').tooltip({placement: 'right'});
    });
```